# Spring security и бан IP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Есть ли встроенная возможность в Spring Security банить пользователя по IP после определённого количества раз ввода пароля неверно? Или решение только через реализацию своего провайдера?

Comment: чтобы не смогли подобрать пароль? много статей по этому поводу, сам фреймворк позволяет это делать. рекомендую ознакомиться со статьей  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - можно использовать Spring Security's Web Security Expressions.
Например:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
    ...
</http>
```

А так же можно написать свой CustomAuthProvider, и в нём получить IP адрес пользователя, вот так:

```
 wad = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        userIPAddress = wad.getRemoteAddress();
```

А дальше всё в наших руках :)

Comment: эта статья больше подходит http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts  но спасибо за информацию